# Como receber dados únicos em asp net mvc

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Possuo o seguinte model chamado `Conta`:

```
public int Codigo { get; set; }
public string Nome { get; set; }
public int Prazo { get; set; }
```

supondo que eu queira fazer um select (sem usar o lambda) e trazer apenas a propriedade Nome, nesse caso eu criei uma struct:

```
struct getNomeConta
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

e fiz o select:

```
getNomeConta = db.Database.SqlQuery<getNomeConta>(strSql).FirstOrDefault();
```

onde `strSQl` é minha string SQL que trás o valor do nome apenas.

Esse código foi feito as pressas pra atender o requisitante, porém quero mudar ele, de preferencia usando lambda para fazer o select, porém trazendo apenas o nome (sem precisar carregar o model `Conta` inteiro)

Comment: Na verdade ao trazer os dados de `Conta` você carrega o *Model* todo de qualquer forma. Trazer todas as colunas ou não não gera impacto sobre o desempenho, se é esta a preocupação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Lambda Expression***

***Obs: Db é seu DbContexto***

```
IList<String> Nomes = db.Conta.Select(x => x.Nome).ToList(); // para lista de nomes
String Nome = db.Conta.Where(x = x.Codigo == 1).Select(x => x.Nome).FirstOrDefault(); // 1 nome
```

**Outra dica:**

Poderia usar o código que você fez mas, nem precisa criar uma *Struct*. Como é só o Nome e o mesmo deve ser uma `VarChar` (`String`) poderia ser assim:

```
String Nome = db.Database.SqlQuery<String>("SELECT Nome FROM Conta Where Codigo = 1").FirstOrDefault();
```

**Obs:** *Só vai criar uma `Struct` ou `Classe` quando essa `SQL` trouxer mais dados.*

Comment: Exatamente. Existe um link explicando o básico sobre isso: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: Otima resposta! Obrigado!